# Make matrix out of the dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I have this data (taken part of random data coming from some server):

```
 data={2: [9, ['b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']], 3: [9,
 ['c', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']], 5: [5, ['c', 'b', 'a',
 'b', 'b']], 7: [9, ['c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']]}
```

In this data, first number is the key, second value is the number of entries in the bracket following it. eg:-
For data

> 2: [9, ['b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']]

2 is the key. 9 is the total number of entries in the bracket which follows it.

Also, for keys having second value less than 9 are to be discarded. 
I got that data.values() can give me the value as

> [[9, ['b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']], [9, ['c',
>   'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']], [5, ['c', 'b', 'a', 'b',
>   'b']], [9, ['c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']]}

But I am not able to find any way to index within the matrix.

I need to make matrix out of this data as follows:

```
     a    b    c
2    4    5    0
3    4    4    1
7    4    3    2
```

The matrix value [1][1] is the sum of a's in key value 2, [1][2] is the sum of b's in key value 2 and [1][3] is the sum of c's in key value 2, [2][1] is the sum of a's in key value 3, and so on..

Comment: So you need it to have specific order, if the first entry was the key 2, you need to access it in the matrix using the first/second/whatever position it had, not the value of the key, right? I mean it because dictionary's don't have specific order, so the keys are not in any given order.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @valeas No. If key=2, then from the data of **2: [9, ['b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']]**, we simply count the occurrence of a,b and c's; and so on for other keys.

Comment: Then if you can access the new matrix using the original key, I would go with @reut-sharabani 's answer

Comment: @valeas Thanks for that information. Is there a way to skip items in it. Like in this, I want to skip 5 as it has value less than 9 (as others have)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably Reut Sharabani's answer is better and faster, but here's how I would do it :

```
data = {
    2: [9, ['b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']],
    3: [9, ['c', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']],
    5: [5, ['c', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b']],
    7: [9, ['c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']]
}

matrix = {key: {k: val[1].count(k) for k in set(val[1])} for key, val in data.iteritems() if val[0] >=9}
```

Which will give you :

```
{2: {'a': 4, 'b': 5},
 3: {'a': 4, 'b': 4, 'c': 1},
 5: {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 1},
 7: {'a': 4, 'b': 3, 'c': 2}}
```

And, of course, use the `.get('c', 0)` so you get 0's for values which are 0.

*Edited to adapt to original question, keys below 9 must be discarded.

Comment: Thanks for that info. 
Is there a way to skip the key 5 containing value <9

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Collections.Counter`:

from collections import Counter

```
data = {
    2: [9, ['b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']],
    3: [9, ['c', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']],
    5: [5, ['c', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b']],
    7: [9, ['c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']]}

matrix = {k: Counter(v[1]) for k, v in data.iteritems() if v[0] >= 9}
```

The value of `matrix` is now:

```
{
     2: Counter({'b': 5, 'a': 4}),
     3: Counter({'a': 4, 'b': 4, 'c': 1}),
     7: Counter({'a': 4, 'b': 3, 'c': 2})
}
```

Accessing a member of the matrix can be done as follows:

```
matrix[2].get('a', 0)
```

(**Note**: using `dict.get` is to make the default return `0`, which indicates no occurences so the key is not created in the `Counter` object).

Which will give the value:

```
4
```

Comment: good answer - possibly worth highlighting that the use of `get` will report the zeroes required, e.g.`matrix[0].get('c', 0)` is 0.

Comment: @valeas No. Order is specific. I have edited the question.